# How can get this tool tip on top?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having trouble getting my tooltips on the top, some of the tool-tips are not visible on smaller screen sizes

[image]

I have set its position and z-index, but still it is not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the value of z-index will not show it as `#price-table-fix` is hiding all overflowed content that is outside the block.

Add rules and property below and it should fix it.

```
#price-table-fix {
    overflow: visible;
}
```